# Edit rejects due to others editing the same time

Tags: bug

I bring this up as it has happened a few times now. My edits get rejected because someone else beat me to the punch. Just now it was right in the middle of a review process.

So two key questions:

Is there no locking involved when I have the item for review? (Seems not as it was edited while I was editing)

My "reputation" is tarnished by saying I have edited x posts and y were rejected and some of those rejections are not my fault due to this concurrent edit ability.

As an Example: https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/123092

Changes are the same because someone else edited seconds before I did.

```
After thought...
```

Although I accept the answer, why does it allow me to edit a post that has not been reviewed?

That in my eye makes it a bug.

Comment: That someone else was @Mitch.

Comment: @Lucio thats not the point, the point is that the situation occured

Comment: The reputation is the point.

Comment: It should have a lock.  I've seen it before, something to the fact that another user is editing please wait until there edit is done, and then you can edit or something like that.  I don't know if it still exist.  Sorry for beating you to it.

Comment: @Mitch I was more concerned from a data integrity point of view but thanks for the thought ;)

Comment: See also http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5995/review-edit-interface-is-misleading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If have less than 2K rep. you are not able to make edits until someone else review it.

If you have more than that among of reputation you will be able to edit a post *no matter how edit this one **before**.*

---

So what happened is that @Mitch edit the post.
And seconds later, you edit the post doing *the same* changes than him, but this edit is valid so it's added to the review queue.
Then, the users how review it saw that *your* edit, is exactly the same that the previously one. That is why it is rejected.

*I know this is not clear, bear with me..*

---

I'm not saying that *how it works now* is the better way. No. I'm just telling you *why* did this happened.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, I accept that situation, just good to know why, thank you for spending the time

Comment: Yes, I know. It's just a weird behaviour, because it is the same edit. I tell you this because it happened to me before :)